How to suppress specific warnings when compiling Kotlin?
I'm trying to compile a Kotlin project and suppress all console outputs that have to do with the deprecated annotations. But I want to keep all other warnings that the project may have.
I've tried this without much success:
allprojects {
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xsuppress-deprecated-jvm-target-warning"
        }
    }
}


According to Kotlin bug tracker (KT-8087), global suppression of individual warnings was released in Kotlin 2.1.0.
It is available under compiler flag -Xsuppress-warning=WARNING_NAME, so in your case it will look like this:
allprojects {
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs.addAll(listOf(
                "-Xsuppress-warning=WARNING_NAME",
                "-Xsuppress-warning=SECOND_SUPPRESSED_WARNING_NAME",
            ))
        }
    }
}

You can find more information in the relevant part of the 2.1.0 release notes.
